# Count the occurrence of each word in a phrase using javascript

Tags: javascript, jasmine

For example for the input `"olly olly in come free"`

The program should return:

`olly: 2
in: 1
come: 1
free: 1`

The tests are written as:

```
var words = require('./word-count');

describe("words()", function() {
  it("counts one word", function() {
    var expectedCounts = { word: 1 };
    expect(words("word")).toEqual(expectedCounts);
  });

//more tests here
});
```

1. How do I start in my word-count.js file? Create a method words() or a module Words() and make an expectedCount method in there and export it?
2. Do I treat the string as an array or an object? In the case of objects, how do I start breaking them into words and iterate for the count?

Answer (score 9):

```js
function count(str) {
  var obj = {};
  
  str.split(" ").forEach(function(el, i, arr) {
    obj[el] = obj[el] ? ++obj[el] : 1;
  });
  
  return obj;
}

console.log(count("olly olly in come free"));
```

This code should get just what you want.
For more understanding on the code I would advice you to go through array prototype functions and string prototype functions.
For simple understanding of what I`m doing here:

1. Create a count function which returns an object of count of all occurrences of words.
2. Split the string using `split(" ")` based on a space which gives an array.
3. Use `forEach` method to iterate through all the elements in the spitted array.
4. Ternary operator `:?` to check if value already exists, if it does increment by one or assign it to 1.

[Array.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/prototype)
[String.prototype](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/prototype)

Comment: xBrowser note: `forEach was added to the ECMA-262 standard in the 5th edition`

Comment: Also, if you need to make it case insensitive `el = el.toLowerCase();` might help.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you do it

**word-count.js**

```
function word-count(phrase){
    var result = {};  // will contain each word in the phrase and the associated count
    var words = phrase.split(' ');  // assuming each word in the phrase is separated by a space

    words.forEach(function(word){
        // only continue if this word has not been seen before
        if(!result.hasOwnProperty(word){
            result[word] = phrase.match(/word/g).length;
        }
    });

    return result;
}

exxports.word-count = word-count;
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the simplest function to count words:

```
export function wordCount(input) {
    const words = input.split(' ');
    const result = {};
    words.forEach(word => {
        result[word] = result[word] + 1 || 1;
    });
    return result;
}
```