# How to count the number of instances of each type?

Tags: javascript, object

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'fencing'];

const sports = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item]) //to create an object if it doesn't exist
    obj[item] = 0;
  else
    obj[item]++; //to increment the object count if it exist
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(sports);
```

Output I'm receiving:

> Object { soccer: 0, basketball: 0, badminton: 0, swimming: 0, squash: 0, fencing: 0 }

Output I want:

> Object { soccer: 5, basketball: 3, badminton: 2, swimming: 2, squash: 2, fencing: 1 }

What's going wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In JavaScript, zero [evaluates to `false`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy).
So `!obj[item]` is `true` when `obj[item] == 0` and nothing ever gets incremented.

```js
const obj = {
  'soccer': 0
};

// true
console.log(!obj['basketball']);

// also true!
console.log(!obj['soccer']);
```

One solution is to initialize new properties to 1 rather than 0. No value can ever be zero anyway because each property exists at least once in the dataset, and this avoids confusing zero with undefined.

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'fencing'];

const sports = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  if (!obj[item])
    obj[item] = 1; // initialize property to 1 if it is falsy
  else
    obj[item]++; // otherwise increment the value
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(sports);
```

But in my opinion, the `else` is unnecessary and [Andy's method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68242509/924299) is a bit simpler.

Just for fun, here's another method using a [ternary operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator):

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'fencing'];

const sports = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item] = obj[item] ? obj[item] + 1 : 1;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(sports);
```

And [another method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690820/924299) from [snak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1378868/snak):

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'fencing'];

const sports = data.reduce(function(obj, item) {
  obj[item] = (obj[item] || 0) + 1;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(sports);
```

For reference, also see:
[How to increment an object property value if it exists, else set the initial value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18690814/how-to-increment-an-object-property-value-if-it-exists-else-set-the-initial-val)
[short javascript code for: initialize to zero or increment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13298232/short-javascript-code-for-initialize-to-zero-or-increment)
[Count the occurrence of each word in a phrase using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26825786/count-the-occurrence-of-each-word-in-a-phrase-using-javascript)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `else`. Set the value to zero if the property doesn't exist, then add one to it.

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball','fencing'];

const sports = data.reduce(function(obj, item){
    if(!obj[item]) obj[item] = 0;
    obj[item]++;
    return obj;
 }, {});

console.log(sports);
```

Comment: thanks it worked , but why its not working with the else statement

Answer (score 0):

Additional to other answers: this can be a one liner:

```js
const data = ['soccer', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'basketball', 'badminton', 
  'swimming', 'soccer', 'squash', 'badminton', 'swimming', 'soccer', 
  'squash', 'soccer', 'basketball', 'fencing'];
console.log(
  data.reduce( (acc, value) => ({...acc, [value]: (acc[value] || 0) + 1}), {} )
);
```